# what is the best? present or future in this case

Tags: present-simple

> When the order is big enough he, then, **sends** it to me
>
> When the order is big enough he, then, **will send** it to me

As it is a general statement I think present sends is better

Comment: both work, will may mean a usual action. Then is of no use here, imo. Mind, I'm not a NS.

Comment: Both are correct, they mean different things. One is general, the other is specific.

Answer (score 2):

General statement:

When the order is big enough, he **sends i**t to me. [to explain a policy, for example]

When the order is big enough, **he will send it** to me. [telling someone this for a specific thing].

Here's another example of this:

What **will you do** when he arrives?[I will x when he arrives; specific]

What **do you do** when he arrives? [present simple for general things]

The present simple is for a general statement and the will +verb is for a specific instance of something.

Comment: What is specific in the following phrases: _When you look at clouds they will often remind you of animals. 
If something breaks down and you kick it, it will often start working again. What will you usually do when he arrives?_

Comment: @MvLog  I am explaining it for this context. And "will" is not for a usual action. I repeat: "What do you do when he arrives?" **is not** "What will you do when he arrives?". The first is usual, the second is that he will arrive at some point.

Comment: @Lambie - The difference is subtle – almost imperceptible, unless we think about it. But I think you've described it well. The first one sounds like something I'd tell someone on their first day at a new job. The second one sounds more like when I'm explaining to someone why we need to wait for a particular shipment. But it's less about a difference in meaning, and more about which I'd be more likely to use in a particular situation.

Comment: @J.R. Exactly. That is exactly my point. Thanks for helping me make it.